# Toggle button for three.js GUI

Tags: user-interface, boolean, dat.gui

Simple question is there a simple on/off button for three.js gui?

```
var params =
{
     switch: 0
};

// on/off button
gui.add(params, "light switch").min(0).max(1).step(1)

gui.open();
```

This is what I have so far, but you have to slide the value left or right, which is counter-intuitive. I just want the user to.be able to click on teh button switching it on and off.

Sort of like this:

[image: three.js gui button]

For all your invisible elephant needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a checkbox to your GUI, you only have to define `switch` as a boolean.

```js
var params = {
    switch: false
};

gui.add(params, "switch").name("light switch");
gui.open();
```

Comment: That's more of a checkbox, I was after a chunkier button :)

Comment: What do you mean with "chunkier" button? Do you mind updating the question with an image that shows the intended UI? Keep in mind that you could style the checkbox according to your needs with CSS.

Comment: I've added a animated gif to show what I had in mind.

Comment: As @Mugen87 mentioned, you can "chunkify" your button with CSS. Works great!